# How to say we provide a synopsis here for details refer to other work in formal academic writing

Tags: phrases, expressions, technical, academia

> We provide here a synopsis of the measurement process, for an in-depth
>   description, please refer to XYZ.

I'm not a native speaker. How do I write that as the first sentence of a chapter in an academic, technical paper?

Also, do I use the word "please" or omit it in formal, technical writing? As in "for an in-depth discussion, please refer to XYZ".

Comment: What does "here" allude to in this context? IE: Chapter 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility:

*A summary of the measurement process is presented below; for an in-depth description, refer to XYZ.*

Comment: Yes. The comma-splice in the original needed correcting, but this reads better.